# Animation of drawing does not work in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgTJx.png)

I have created a custom UIButton class where I'm filling its inside with a color but only partially.

The Goal:
The goal is to fill inside of the button with background color but only partially. For example you have a long button(height: 50.0, width: 300.0). I want to fill it with background color horizontally, let's say only for 50%. In this case only the half of my button will be filled with color, another half will stay transparent or white.

The entire class looks like this:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    var color: UIColor = .clear
    var percentage: CGFloat = 0

    func fill(withPercentage percentage: CGFloat, isCorrect correct: Bool, onRect rect: CGRect) {
        self.color = correct ? .lightishGreen : .pastelRed
        self.percentage = percentage

        draw(rect)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        let fillRect = CGRect(
            origin: CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x, y: rect.origin.y),
            size: CGSize(width: rect.size.width * percentage, height: rect.size.height)
        )
        color.set()

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        context.fill(fillRect)
    }
}
```

and this class works perfectly. However, I want to animate this drawing process, so the button is getting filled with background color from 0.0 to 1.0 let's say.

I've tried to put `context.fill(fillRect)` inside of the `UIView.animate(){}` but it did not work. So I wondered, is it possible to animate drawing?

I just do not want to make button bg color clear and to put UIView behind it and simulate filling there. Wanted a clean way. So I will be happy, if someone can give me a hint or show me how to do it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes ... you need to show what you want to achieve ?

Comment: @matt I've updated the question. Tried to make it more clear and added a screenshot

Comment: @jawadAli I've added a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want a custom animatable property. Let's call it `percentage`. Here's one way:

```
class MyView : UIView {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    override class var layerClass : AnyClass {
        return MyLayer.self
    }
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {}
}
class MyLayer : CALayer {
    @NSManaged var percentage : CGFloat
    override class func needsDisplay(forKey key: String) -> Bool {
        if key == #keyPath(percentage) {
            return true
        }
        return super.needsDisplay(forKey:key)
    }
    override func action(forKey key: String) -> CAAction? {
        if key == #keyPath(percentage) {
            let ba = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: key)
            ba.fromValue = self.presentation()!.value(forKey:key)
            return ba
        }
        return super.action(forKey:key)
    }
    override func draw(in con: CGContext) {
        con.setFillColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
        let rect = self.bounds.insetBy(dx: 2, dy: 2)
        let rounded = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 20)
        con.addPath(rounded.cgPath)
        con.setStrokeColor(UIColor.lightGray.cgColor)
        con.strokePath()
        con.addPath(rounded.cgPath)
        con.clip(using: .evenOdd)
        let fillRect = CGRect(
            origin: CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x, y: rect.origin.y),
            size: CGSize(width: rect.size.width * percentage, height: rect.size.height)
        )
        con.fill(fillRect)
    }
}
```

The result is that when you set this view's layer's `percentage`, the change is animated:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer! But I cannot call it =/ Could you please help me? I tried to do `myButton.layerClass.percentage = XX` but it does not work. I really appreciate your time!

Comment: Try `myButton.layer.percentage = xx`. Even better, use a CABasicAnimation for real control over the animation.

Comment: thank you! I've used it but the percentage value does not work. When I set `percentage = 50.0` then the entire button is getting filled. Do you know what might cause it?

Comment: Fifty percent would be `0.5`.